# StreamCorruptedException in Android

Tags: java, android

So I have to implement a recommendation system with an Android client. The system works like this: a user sends its location and the number of desired recommendations to the server. Then the server produces the recommendations and sends back the recommended Pois (Points Of Interest).

Here is my problem. When the client reads the `Pois[]` array (the actual recommendations) from the server, a `StreamCorruptedException` is thrown. The odd thing is that this never happens when I run the app on my own computer. It only happens when I run it on my university's computers. And it doesn't happen *always*. It happens probably 8/10 times I run it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the exception.

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 3A
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java.1521)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1772)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1992)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1916)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream(1799)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1707)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1345)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readUnshared(ObjectInputStream.java:463)
    at client.ds2018.ClientActivity$Fetcher.fetch(ClientActivity.java:283)
    at client.ds2018.ClientActivity$Fetcher.doInBackground(ClientActivity.java:311)
    at client.ds2018.ClientActivity$Fetcher.doInBackground(ClientActivity.java:256)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java.1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

And here is the code.
This is the `Poi` class. An array of these is sent as a response to the client.

```
public class Poi implements Serializable
{
    private int id; // Poi id
    private byte[] image; // Binary representation of location's image.
    private double latitude, longitude;
    private String name, category, imageURL; // The url address of the image.

    // Constructor, getters & setters[...]
}
```

This the `ClientActivity` class (the client).

```
public class ClientActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback
{
    private Fetcher f; // The async task that fetches the Pois.
    private Poi[] recs; // Recommendations array.
    private int uid, k; // User id and number of recommendations.

    private class Fetcher extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Poi[]>
    {
        Poi poi;
        int k, uid;
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        Socket request = null;
        ObjectInputStream in = null;
        ObjectOutputStream out = null;

        Fetcher(Poi poi, int k, int uid)
        {
            this.k = k;
            this.uid = uid;
            this.poi = poi;
        }

        @Override 
        protected Poi[] doInBackground(Void... v)
        {
            Poi[] result = null;

            try
            {
                request = new Socket(IP_ADDRESS, PORT);
                out = new ObjectOutputStream(request.getOutputStream());
                in = new ObjectInputStream(request.getInputStream());

                result = fetch(); // <-- Gets null.
            }
            catch(IOException ioExc)
            {
                ioExc.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    out.close();
                    in.close();
                    request.close();
                }
                catch(IOException ioExc)
                {
                    ioExc.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        Poi[] fetch() throws IOException
        {
            Poi[] recs = null;

            try
            {
                out.writeInt(uid);
                out.writeUnshared(LOCATION);
                out.writeInt(k);
                out.flush();

                recs = (Poi[]) in.readUnshared(); // <-- This is where the exception is thrown, readUnshared returns null.
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfExc)
            {
                cnfExc.printStackTrace();
            }

            return recs; // <-- Returns null.
        }

    private static final Poi LOCATION = // The location sent to the Server...;
}
```

This is the `Master` class (the server). The server reads the a JSON file containing the data for the locations (longitude, latitude, image URL, etc).
When the recommendations are produced, it downloads the images and sends all the information back to the client. Every time a client is connected to the server, a `Handler` thread is created to serve the client.

```
public class Master
{
   private JSONObject pois;

   //  Constructor.
   public Master() { initialize(); }

   private void openServer()
   {
        // Do stuff[...]
        try
        {
            Thread t;
            //  Awaiting clients.
            System.out.println("Awaiting clients...\n");
            provider = new ServerSocket(C_PORT, BACKLOG);

            while(true)
            {
                connection = provider.accept();
                System.out.println("Client connected.");

                //  Creating request handler.
                t = new Handler(connection);

                t.start();
            }
           catch{Exception exc) {...}
           finally
           {
               try
               {
                   //  Closing server.
                   provider.close();
               }
               catch(IOException ioExc)
               {
                   ioExc.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       }


       //  Returns the recommendations.
       private synchronized Poi[] getRecommendations(int u, int k, Poi poi)
       {
           // Produce recommendations...
       }

       // The Handler class handles the client requests.
       private class Handler extends Thread
       {
           private Poi poi;    //  POI received by the client.
           /*
            *  k: multitude of POIs to recommend.
            *  u: user id.
            */
            private int k, u;
            private Poi[] recs;     // Recommendations for the client.
            private Socket connection;

            public Handler(Socket connection) { this.connection = connection; }

            //  Extending Thread class.
            public void run()
            {
                ObjectInputStream in = null;
                ObjectOutputStream out = null;

               try
               {
                   //  Initializing streams.
                   in = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
                   out = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

                   u = in.readInt();       //  User id.
                   poi = (Poi) in.readUnshared();    //  POI.
                   k = in.readInt();       //  Number of POIs.

                   //  Producing recommendations.
                   recs = getRecommendations(u, k, poi);

                   //  Sending recommendations to client.
                   out.writeUnshared(recs); // <-- This does NOT send null.
                   out.flush();
              }
              catch(EOFException oefExc)
              {
                   System.out.println("Client disconnected.\n");
              }
              catch(IOException ioExc)
              {
                   ioExc.printStackTrace();
              }
              catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfExc)
              {
                   cnfExc.printStackTrace();
              }
              finally
              {
                   try
                   {
                        //  Closing streams and socket.
                        in.close();
                        out.close();
                        connection.close();
                   }
                   catch(IOException ioExc)
                   {
                        ioExc.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
      }
```

Comment: I would not use Java ObjectStream for data transmission as it can cause security vulnerabilities in your app. Use a different data transmission protocol standard like JSON, protobuf, ...

Comment: @Robert  Will do. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. Instead of having the server download the images and then send them to the client with all the rest of the data, I had the client download the images itself. I guess there was some kind limitation as to the amount of data I could send.